# Fill auntoincrement with 0 on left side

Tags: mariadb

I am working on an invoice system and I am using MariaDB as the database.
The thing is I have an autoincrement field but I need the data to be Autoincrement and with 10 digits like this:

0000000001

not just the number 1.

is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LPAD`:

```
SELECT
    LPAD(id, 10, '0')
FROM yourTable;
```

While the above should work, technically you should cast the numeric `id` auto increment column to text before using it in `LPAD`.  In which case, you would use this:

```
SELECT
    LPAD(CAST(id AS CHAR(10)), 10, '0')
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo

Comment: This is it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Auto increment fields are numeric fields, so the values are stored in the internal numeric format.
In order to get an output with leading zeros I suggest padding it in the select statement or in the client that displays the values.

Answer (score 0):

The only use for the `(10)` in `INT(10)` is for your Question:

```
id INT(10) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL AUTO_INCREMENT
                    ^^^^^^^^
```